# dataset.dropna(subset = ['col1'])

Tags: python

I have a dataset with shape 138930 X 67. I want to drop all the rows which have missing value on a specific column, 'H40'. The result of value_counts() on the column I am referring to is the following: 
0      75968
1      42234
2      13260
3       3275
 n      2552
4        852
5        176
6         53
7         14
8          4

When I used    dataset.dropna(subset = ['H40']) ,it did nothing. The shape of my dataset did not change. What is the problem? As u can see, the value  ' n', which is between 3 and 4, exists 2552 times, meaning that  my dataset should have been decreased by 2552 rows. Any clue? Do you think that the problem is the ' n' value? I also used

dataset = dataset[pd.notnull(dataset['H40'])]
dataset.shape
and it returned the same,
Out[34]: (138390, 67) as if nothing happened

Comment: you need the `inplace=True` flag in your function call

Comment: Well thanks a lot, it worked fine.